# Как добавить строку в цикл?

Tags: циклы, шаблонизаторы, строки

```
foreach my $fish ( sort keys %{$hash} ){
```

В переменной  $fish будет:

```
herring

herring

herring

shark
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при изменении слова добавлялась строка с данными, к примеру:

```
herring

herring

herring

Новая строка - herring с суммой (к примеру)

shark

shark

строка по shark
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте переменную для суммы, когда строка меняется, выводите результат, а переменную обнуляете.